# Why is it necessary to color the root black after every insertion into a Left-Leaning Red-Black Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

In Sedgewick's Left-Leaning Red-Black trees (presented in his [paper](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/LLRB/LLRB.pdf) or his Algorithms [book](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/)), one modification over the standard BST is to color the root node black after each insertion, see `root.color = BLACK` in `insert(Key, Value)`.

I understand that semantically this is necessary, because the root node should never be the left sub-node of a 3-node / 4-node. However, I cannot see why this is necessary in practice, since it seems that the color of the root node is never examined. Could anyone please point out what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After inspecting the code, I reached the same conclusion as you, that the root color is never actually used.

So, I tested a bit to try to confirm this, and in the process I found that there are actually a bunch of small mistakes in the code presented in that paper: calls to methods that are never defined, assignments to variables that are never declared, unnecessary repetition of expensive method calls, unused object references (=pointers), and so on.

Of course, none of these is a very serious issue, in that none of them requires much effort to fix; but I think your question would only really make sense if the code were *perfect*, or nearly so, which it simply isn't. Given that the code has dozens of compile-errors and several glaringly non-optimal bits that *don't* involve the red–black semantics, I don't think it makes sense to quibble over whether it *really* needs to set the root node color in the semantically-expected way.

But for what it's worth, my testing suggests that the root color indeed does not matter; I wrote a validation method that verifies the appropriate invariants (that no red *non-root* node has a red child, and that all leaf nodes have equal black-depths), and I found that these were preserved whether or not I commented out the lines to set the root color to black. (Of course, that only demonstrates it for the cases I tested, but still, it was enough to give me greater confidence in the conclusion. Specifically, my cases involved adding the keys 1 through 1000 in order, in reverse order, or in randomly-shuffled order, then removing them in order, in reverse order, or in randomly-shuffled order. I validated the invariants after each individual insertion or deletion.)

Comment: I was mainly referencing the code accompanying his Algorithm book ([RedBlackBST.java](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/edu/princeton/cs/algs4/RedBlackBST.java.html)). This code is compilable and is of better quality than presented in the paper, but I agree that this is far from perfect either. Actually I can find one case where coloring the root black will make a difference: if you uncomment the assertions in the code, the assertion in `flipColors(Node)` will fail because it checks whether a node has a different color as its children.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, what made me really confused is the fact that it was specifically called out in his Algorithms book (4th edition, page 437) that the root needs to be colored black but no reason is provided. Interestingly, many other implementations of LLRB do this as well, e.g. [C#](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/9686081), [C](https://github.com/wolkykim/qlibc/blob/master/src/containers/qtreetbl.c), and [C++](http://www.teachsolaisgames.com/articles/balanced_left_leaning.html).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be no different for standard red-black trees: the convention is that the root should be black. This is nothing more than a convention as in theory the root node could be (left) red without violating any of the (other) red-black tree properties. Such color change does not affect the additional properties for left-leaning red-black trees either.

See property #2 in [Red-black tree - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties):

> 2. The root is black. This rule is sometimes omitted. Since the root can always be changed from red to black, but not necessarily vice versa, this rule has little effect on analysis.

**In short**: coloring the root node black is not *necessary*, but done by convention.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because you need rebuilt the tree, to make tree is AVL. When you insert a new node, root node could be change to another node and needed re-color for root.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The only mechanism for changing the root during insertion is left– or right-rotation; and both of those transfer the color from the old root to the new root.

Comment: I don't understand, you said same with my opinion. Why it wrong? as you know "mechanism for changing the root during insertion is left– or right-rotation" to make sure this tree  became a balanced tree

Answer (score 0):

What coloring the root black does is simplify the checks that need to be performed. If you color the root black and run into a red violation you know (without further testing) that the current node's parent is not the root and therefore that the current node has a grandparent as well. In trees I have worked on it is far less expensive to perform a color check than to check whether the current node is the root.